# 406 error with OData service in Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to figure out why my odata service doesn't work to no avail. I keep getting a 406 error and I have tried all recommended solutions to no avail. Below is my code.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : ODataController
{

[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Person> GetTest()
{
        try
        {
            var persons = new List<Person>(){new Person{ Id= 1}};
            return persons.AsQueryable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var here = "dd";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In my webapiconfig class, I have:

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();         

        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
                 builder.EntitySet<Person>("Person"); 
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

It keeps failing with 406 error. It hits the breakpoint in my controller, but does not return the data.

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: have you tried `[Queryable]` instead of `[EnableQuery]` attribute?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception in the code, just 406 error on fiddler or any client. @JotaBe, it's not a duplicate. Queryable is deprecated and does not work.

Comment: Which version are you using? Have you tried creating a "tutorial version" of the application using the VS default scaffolding and checked if it works? (Tutorial version: create EF model, add OData packages, use VS scaffolding) Could it be a CORS issue? Have you tried "Accept=*/*" header in your request? Can you show all the headers of the request to teh Odata service, as captured by Fiddler or console?

Comment: I figured out the problem and I hope this helps someone else. I was using config.MapODataServiceRoute(... instead of config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute... As soon as I changed it, and had the right using statements, everything started working. Thanks for all your help guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was using `config.MapODataServiceRoute(...` instead of `config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute...` As soon as I changed it, and had the right using statements, everything started working.